# How to sub query a filter in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to filter my accounts table by when they closed and only show the closed accounts where the customer has been active in the last month.

I have 4 tables.
Calendar, 
Customer, 
Accounts, 
Logins.

I have linked the account to the customer, the customer to the logins and the accounts to the calendar.

The 3 tables are also connected to the calendar by date. 
Account Close Date, 
Customer Open Date, 
Login Date.

I have tried doing Calculate(ClosedAccounts, filter(LoginTable, MonthLogins > 5)).

ClosedAccounts = Calculate(count(accountnumber), accountstatus = "Closed")

MonthLogins calculates the last 30 days logins for me.

The issue is going from the accounts table through the customer table to the login table.

I think the issue is that the relationships from the accounts to customer to login tables are the "Inactive" Link. So I assume I am missing a UserRelationship() somewhere but not sure where.

I am expecting to return the accounts that were closed in each month where the customer had more than 5 logins in the last month.

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Tables]

Comment: Please provide the relation overview snapshot

Comment: @Aldert I have attached a snapshot of the tables.